# Python bitwise operations confusion

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, id3

I came up with this "magic string" to meet the ID3 tagging specification:

> The ID3v2 tag size is encoded with four bytes where the most significant bit (bit 7) is set to zero in every byte, making a total of 28 bits. The zeroed bits are ignored, so a 257 bytes long tag is represented as $00 00 02 01.

```
>>> hex_val = 0xFFFFFFFF
>>> str.format('0b{0:07b}{1:07b}{2:07b}{3:07b}', ((hex_val >> 24) & 0xEF),
                                                 ((hex_val >> 16) & 0xEF), 
                                                 ((hex_val >>  8) & 0xEF),
                                                 ((hex_val >>  0) & 0xEF))
'0b11101111111011111110111111101111'
```

Why does it not equal:

```
'0b11111111111111111111111111111111'
```

?

If anyone cares, this seems to work:

```
>>> int(str.format('0b{0:07b}{1:07b}{2:07b}{3:07b}', ((hex_val >> 24) & 0xFE),
                                                     ((hex_val >> 16) & 0xFE),
                                                     ((hex_val >>  8) & 0xFE), 
                                                     ((hex_val >>  0) & 0xFE)), 2)
```

Comment: >>> str.format('0b{0:07b}{1:07b}{2:07b}{3:07b}', ((hex_val >> 24) & 0x7F), ((hex_val >> 16) & 0x7F), ((hex_val >> 8) & 0x7F), ((hex_val >> 0) & 0x7F))
    '0b1111111111111111111111111111'

Sorry, getting my E and 7s confused.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing the and and the or operations.

- bitwise and: return a number with only bits that are in both operands set.
- bitwise or: return a number with bits that are in either of the operands set.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry getting my 7s and Es confused

Corrected code:

```
>>> str.format('0b{0:07b}{1:07b}{2:07b}{3:07b}', ((hex_val >> 24) & 0x7F),
                                                 ((hex_val >> 16) & 0x7F),
                                                 ((hex_val >>  8) & 0x7F),
                                                 ((hex_val >>  0) & 0x7F))
```

Comment: You should correct the question rather than add an answer (sorry to contradict the other advice, I guess Carl thought you were someone other than the original poster). (Oh, and I think kaizer.se has the right answer).

Answer (score 1):

It does not equal all ones because you're masking out the 4th bit using the `&` operator!